# angularjs ui-grid set selectedItems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to upgrade from ng-grid to ui-grid and i had no idea how to set the selected items on init.
Short explanation: I'm loading data from a database where some items are marked as shown to normal users and some not. When you open the app as admin the complete list should load an the marked items should be checked in the grid.
In ng-grid i had set the selectedItems property but in ui-grid this doesn't work anymore.
How does this work in the new ui-grid version?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem with a table inside a popup.

We solved by calling selection api upon rendering with the following code:

```
var onRowsRendered = function(gridApi) {
  rowsToSelect.forEach(function(row) {
    gridApi.selection.selectRow(row);
  }
};
```

Then inside of `onRegisterApi`:

```
gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope, onRowsRendered);
```

PS: `rowsToSelect` is supposed to be a subset of row entities (i.e. an array made of some of the element of `gridOptions.data`)

Comment: That does it! Thanks. Isn't there an easier way? I thought about overwriting the rowTemplate and set the ui-grid-row-selected class in a ng-class condition.